# GWT Table component with grouping, header sorting and grouping

Tags: gwt, datatable, gridview-sorting

I'm looking for a GWT table component with header sorting, grouping with subfooters and normal footer. I basically want to sum fields for all the groups as well as a total sum  in main footer.

Anyone know if there exists any good table component for this, or do I need to build my own.
I'm not looking for any commercial frameworks as ext-gwt or GXT more incubator style :)